# Ionic IOS Google Log-In mobile "location.protocol" Cordova

Tags: ios, typescript, firebase, cordova, google-signin

So I'm having trouble with Google Log-In on IOS with mobile applications.

Originally my code was

auth.service.ts

```
constructor(
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private afs: AngularFirestore,
  private router: Router
) {
  this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        return this.afs.doc<any>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
      } else {
        return of(null);
      }
    })
  );
}

googleSignIn() {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
}
private async oAuthLogin(provider) {
  const credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  return this.updateUserData(credential.user);
}

private updateUserData({ uid, email, displayName, photoURL }) {
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${uid}`);

  const data = {
    uid,
    email,
    displayName,
    photoURL
  };
  __email = email;
  __id = uid;
  this.router.navigate(['/tabs']);
  return userRef.set(data, { merge: true });
}
```

With this code, everything works perfects on Web and Android.
A pop-up is displayed and I am able to sign-in with Google.

IOS throws an error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise):  Error: This operation is not supported in the environment this 
application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and 
web storage must be enabled.
```

So I added some Cordova plugins as my app is using both Capacitor and Cordova.

The Official Firebase Cordova Google-Log-In document

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

However, the code the documentation also doesn't seem to run on IOS either.

`signInWithPopup()` `signInWithRedirect()` `linkWithPopup()` and `linkWithRedirect()`

All cause the same error as before.

Also seems Google doesn't allow web-view log-in anymore

https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it!!

https://jsmobiledev.com/article/ionic-google-login

This link helped me out a lot. Took me awhile to fully implement all of it, but it works for ionic 4.

All steps in link must be completed.

end code:

auth.service.ts

```
constructor(
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private afs: AngularFirestore,
  private router: Router,
  private googlePlus: GooglePlus,
) {
  this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
        return this.afs.doc<any>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
      } else {
        return of(null);
      }
    })
  );
}


googleSignIn() {
  this.googlePlus.login({
    'webClientId': 'THIS_IS_YOUR_WEB_CLIENT_ID',
    'offline': false
  }).then( res => {
   this.afAuth.signInWithCredential
   (firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken))
      .then( success => {
        console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
    
        return this.updateUserData(success.user);
      })
      .catch( error => console.log("Firebase failure: " + 
      JSON.stringify(error)));
    }).catch(err => console.error("Error: ", err));
}


private updateUserData({ uid, email, displayName, photoURL }) {
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${uid}`);

  const data = {
    uid,
    email,
    displayName,
    photoURL
  };
  __email = email;
  __id = uid;
  this.router.navigate(['/tabs']);
  return userRef.set(data, { merge: true });
}
```